# GET url parameters Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

There is one view, and one controller, it is necessary, with the use of the get parameter, to change the path by the link. So in the end it turned out like this:

Upcoming -> `http://mywebsite.com/tournaments?type=upcoming`

Finished -> `http://mywebsite.com/tournaments?type=finished`

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please specify?

Comment: How to implement it!?

Comment: If possible using the code example

Comment: How to pass the paramters in URL using GET right?

Comment: That's exactly what you need

Comment: The logic is this:
1) there is no get parameter of type or unfamiliar - we load everything
2) is, type = upcoming - we load upcoming
3) is, type = finished - loading completed

Comment: Check my code I have written long code especially for u

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller which will process your GET variable

```
Controller
<?php 
    class Demo_controller extends CI_Controller 
    {
      public function demo($id)
      {
         echo $id; //the id which you will get in URL string
      }
     }
?>
```

View File where you will pass the Variable

```
<?php
$id = "1";//dyanmic id which will be pased with the form
echo form_open('demo/demos-function'.$id);
//in between your code
echo form_close
?>

Routes
Inside routes.php
$route['demo/demos-function/(:any)] = Demo_controller/demo/$1
```

No need to change the $1 it will explain the routes that it is having URL paramater.
So Ultimately Your link will be

```
https://localhost/demo/demos-function/1
https://localhost/demo/demos-function/2
```

Comment: All this is not bad, but I need this all through if(){} the operator, and do a check if there is a GET parameter then load one view, if not then another ...

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter Url like this :

Upcoming  -> http://mywebsite.com/controller/method/upcoming

Finished -> http://mywebsite.com/controller/method/finished

```
public function method_name()
{
    $type = $this->uri->segment(3); // third level value of URL - Segment(1) is controller and followed by method and query string 

   if($type == 'upcoming')
   {
      echo $type;
     $this->load->view('upcoming');
   }
   else
    {
      echo $type;
      $this->load->view('finished');
    }
}
```